# Installing ANDROID sdk on a MAC OS X

Tags: android, macos, installation

I've been facing issues with my installation of Android sdk on my MAC.

As instructed on the google website I've followed their instructions to install

ADT Plugin

Android SDK

Eclipse platform

The installation is not on this order but as directed by the website. After installation I followed the instructions to create a .bash_profile(it was not present on my computer) and I updated it with the directory settings. Now I've installed it and set the path folder on Eclipse using the preferences->android. When I click apply and I exit I get an error stating that Android component is missing. Also to note that the android sdk->platform is supposed to contain an adb is empty.
[I used this question's solution and yet I get the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692080/cant-install-android-sdk-on-a-mac/%22question%22%22)

Thank you for your input

UPDATE: It asks me to use the SDK manager to install I am unable to locate this component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed any actual Android SDK platforms.

Go to the tools directory of the Android SDK and run android. The Android SDK manager GUI will appear allowing you to install an android platform.  Click on available packages, expand Android repository, and install the platform versions you want.

Comment: Thanks it didn't run on terminal...ran it directly by clicking...Now I can start work Cheers :D